# Not able to find header tags in XPath for Microsoft Edge WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I know that XPath support has been added to Edge as of build 10547, but I'm wondering if there's issues with certain tags like headers (h2, h3, etc)?  https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/

For a simple page like this:

```html
<h2>H2 Header</h2>
```

The XPath locator: *//h2* can't find the element. Other XPaths work fine for me though. Also... *//*[name()='h2']* works fine.

I'm using Build 10586. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me in 10.0.10586

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for trying it out. I was using RemoteWebDriver to connect to a Windows 10 VM, so maybe it's related to that.